# Fix macOS bluetooth microphone audio distorsion while recording with Electron

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, electron, audio-recording

I'm actually facing some issues when I record my screen with audio while using a bluetooth microphone on macOS. The voice is sometimes crackly, sped up, sounds like a robot, or just loud noise.

Here are a few pieces of information:

- I built a custom app to record screen/audio using Electron framework.
- navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is used without any specific configuration.
- I can replicate the problem sometimes with Microsoft Teams, or with others meetings/recording tools.
- The majority of users who have that issue are on macOS (some rarely are on Windows) and every user that has that kind of issue used Bluetooth devices.

Did anyone have already saw something like that?

Comment: To avoid any heavy lifting, would it be possible to provide a simple example that records input audio on a button press and saves to file but also demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem. It's really random. 
But here is a gist for electron fiddle where I had the issue one time without being able to reproduce it. 
https://gist.github.com/BertholetDamien/a6723c526d7e943b56d25eb50dd4d2a2